# Animation in iOS 14 widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I can't find solution to implement kind of ProgressBar in Widget. I see, that Text component should be changed if has type .timer for example. I see default widget Clock, with nice animation of moving arrow. But am I able to implement custom animation in widget?

Comment: From what I heard custom animations are not allowed in widget (probably for optimization reasons).

Comment: I can't find reference on it, but also I see animation on default Clock widget.

Comment: I didn't find any official reference too, but I couldn't manage to get an animation working inside a widget. For the default Clock widget, Apple might be using a private API or something to achieve that (this wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: @rraphael. I think you’re right. It is probably an Apple only feature. Like the clock icon animating or the calendar icon updating daily, features that only Apple can use.

Comment: there are third party Apps, with hand clock animations, not sure how they are doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a Frameworks Engineer on [Developer Apple Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650021):

> Animations and pan/zoom gesture do not work in widgets built with WidgetKits. Checkout https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10028/, where what works and doesn't.

Throughout the WWDC20 Meet WidgetKit video mentioned above, Apple stresses that Widgets are not mini-apps, so they don't support gesture based views (like scroll views) or animations. Widgets are meant to only have glanceable information. From [WWDC20 Meet WidgetKit Video Transcript](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10028/):

> These widgets are not mini-apps. We do not support scrolling within the widget, interactive elements like switches and other system controls, nor videos or animated images.