# Display lottie animation in iOS WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swiftui, lottie, widgetkit

I want to show lottie animation in iOS WidgetKit. I use this project https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios. It works well in APP. But same code not work in WidgetKit.

The code in APP is as bellow, which works well in APP:

```swift
struct widgetTestyView : View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            //Text("\(entry.date)")
            LottieView(animation: LottieAnimation.named("Samples/9squares_AlBoardman")!)

        }
    }
}
```

But same code did not work in WidgetKit, the code is as bellow:

```swift
//
//  widget.swift
//  widget
//

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

struct widgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            //Text("\(entry.date)")
            LottieView(animation: LottieAnimation.named("Samples/9squares_AlBoardman")!)

        }
    }
}

@main
struct widget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "widget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            widgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct widget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        widgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

Is it possible to show lottie in WidgetKit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have Lottie animations **directly within widgets.** In my knowledge, WidgetKit primarily focuses on displaying static and dynamic content such as text, images, and basic UI components. If we look at the documentation, it doesn't say anything about performing a Lottie (or any other package for that matter) animation.

> In addition to the default transitions and animations that the system performs when views update their data, you can choose other built-in SwiftUI transitions and animations.

They only mention about the **already built-in** transitions and animations.

I suggest you take a look at the official documentation about animating widgets, maybe you can find something I missed. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/animating-data-updates-in-widgets-and-live-activities

Comment: Could you have a loot at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74506733/how-to-animate-widgetkit-widgets-like-other-apps-do-it ?

Comment: Wow, there's an example app in that question that somehow found a workaround to this issue. This is really interesting, I hope we can find a way through this.

Comment: Maybe if we can find a way to convert the Lottie animations to actual images and then we can create an animation sequence in the Widget. It could work.

Comment: The refresh interval is less than 1 second, I don't know how it was done